# Using uibinder with SmartGWT?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder

Is it possible to use UiBinder with SmartGWT at all?  I've heard that at the moment it's impossible, though there are efforts to bridge the gap.  How are those efforts?  Have they yielded any successes yet?

Furthermore, if SmartGWT is still not UiBinder-friendly yet, are there any other GWT libraries that might be?  ext-GWT, perhaps?

Comment: I'm using it right now with GWT 2.0.4 and it works perfect. Where did you heard that it's impossible?

Comment: I tried adding SmartGWT to my current app (which uses UiBinder) and it simply doesn't work.  Also here: http://euginel.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/gwt-2-0-uibinder-and-smartgwt-2-0/

1. Individual SmartGWT widgets may be used with UIBinder successfully
2. Using SmartGWT layout elements with UIBinder is NOT currently feasible
3. There are currently NO nice workarounds for this issue

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. I didn't understand what you mean :(

Comment: I've heard it is now possible be used together UIBinder and SmartGWT, but I have not found how to do this. Now I have a project on GWT with UIBinder and I need to integrate SmartGWT into it. Can you explain to me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with UiBinder, but it is possible with GWT Designer which can be [found here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner.html).
Then simply right click on the project or package in which you want to use SmartGWT, select **Google Web Toolkit** and then **Configure for using SmartGWT**.
Hope that gets you started!

***Edit:** GWT-Ext is also included, as you will see when right clicking.*